# Is it possible to send data to AMQP server using AT-Command on ESP8266 Wi-Fi module?

Tags: esp8266, microcontrollers, communication, stm32

I'm currently working on an IoT project which I have an STM32F0 connected to the ESP8266 Wi-Fi module. My goal is to publish data to an AMQP server.

Currently, I'm trying to connect to an AMQP server(cloudAMQP) by controlling the ESP8266 using AT-command. The problem is I don't know how to send data to an AMQP server. All I can think of is I need to construct a data frame that is encoded in binary format and send it over TCP protocol.

Is this a possible approach or is there another way to connect the STM32 to an AMQP server?